# I'm trying to figure out the average, the average of the average, of a series of d6 rolls' value, and total

Tags: python, random, average, dice

I'm trying to figure out the average, the average of the average, of a series of d6 rolls' value, total of a series of d6 rolls, and average total of a series of d6 rolls. I keep getting numbers slightly off, and the variable I have ore both confusing me and I think some are redundant. If someone could help me clean up my code & stuff that would be helpful. I expanded upon Stefan B's code,

````
```python

from random import randint

numRolls = int(input("How many times will you roll the dice? "))
s = 0

for roll in range(numRolls):  
        d1 = randint(1, 6)
        d2 = randint(1, 6)
        s += d1 + d2
        print("You rolled a", d1, "and a", d2)

print("Your total for all of the rolls is", s)
print("Your average for all of the rolls is", s / numRolls)
```
````

and added some of my own code, while not making it two dice rolls - my code:

````
```python
from random import randint

k = 0
x = 0
z = 0
v = 0
a = 0
j = 0
repeat = int(input("How many times would you like to repeat the following command? "))
numRolls = int(input("How many times will you roll the dice? "))
for roll in range(repeat):

  s = 0
  b = 0
  for roll in range(numRolls):
    d6 = randint(1, 6)
    a += d6
    s += d6
    v = v + 1
    y = s / numRolls
    z += y
    k += z
  j = j + 1
  print("Your total for all of the rolls is", s)
  print("Your average for all of the rolls is ", s / numRolls)
rollsets = numRolls / 6
print("Your total average for the total of all rolls is ", z / v)
print("Your total average for all of the rolls is ", a / v)
#print(y)
#print(x)
#print(v)
#print(z)
#print(k)
```
````

I want to do kind of what it does in there, with the multiplying repeat and numRolls variables, and figure out the total and average of one of the small sets of rolls, and the average of both all rolls and the average of the totals.

I tried to use the letter variable to make better averages, but failed. I think I have redundant stuff, and I can't figure out how to measure the number of rolls and 'sets of rolls' for totals. Help please?

Comment: Please tag a language. If this is python, note that correct indentation is essential. Read the help to learn how to properly format code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using more verbose variable names as I think that will help you keep track of what is going on. Conceptually, you want to keep a running total for all rolls of the dice.

```py
from random import randint

number_of_dice = int(input("How many dice will you roll? "))
number_of_rounds = int(input("How many rounds will you roll the dice? "))

sum_all_rolls = 0
sum_all_round_averages = 0

print(f"Rolling {number_of_dice} dice, {number_of_rounds} times")

for round_index in range(number_of_rounds):
    rolls = [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(number_of_dice)]
    sum_this_round = sum(rolls)
    average_this_round = sum_this_round / number_of_dice
    print(f"Round {round_index + 1}. You rolled {rolls} and for a total of {sum_this_round} average {average_this_round}.")

    sum_all_rolls += sum_this_round
    sum_all_round_averages += average_this_round

print(f"Your total for all of the rolls is: {sum_all_rolls}")
print(f"Your average for all of the rolls is: {sum_all_rolls / (number_of_rounds * number_of_dice)}")

print(f"Your total for all round averages is: {sum_all_round_averages}")
print(f"Your average for all round averages is: {sum_all_round_averages/ number_of_rounds}")
```

This will give you a result like:

```
How many dice will you roll? 3
How many rounds will you roll the dice? 6
Rolling 3 dice, 6 times
Round 1. You rolled [3, 4, 4] and for a total of 11 average 3.6666666666666665.
Round 2. You rolled [6, 6, 1] and for a total of 13 average 4.333333333333333.
Round 3. You rolled [4, 3, 2] and for a total of 9 average 3.0.
Round 4. You rolled [3, 2, 1] and for a total of 6 average 2.0.
Round 5. You rolled [4, 5, 6] and for a total of 15 average 5.0.
Round 6. You rolled [5, 6, 3] and for a total of 14 average 4.666666666666667.
Your total for all of the rolls is: 68
Your average for all of the rolls is: 3.7777777777777777
Your total for all round averages is: 22.666666666666668
Your average for all round averages is: 3.777777777777778
```

Comment: What I meant was I re-used Stefan B's code to do my own, but I changed the goal some. I didn't want two d6, but instead a d6 rolled x times per set of rolls in y sets, with the goal of knowing the average roll in each set, total of each set, the overall average of all rolls, and the average total.

Comment: @ObAnon I updated the answer to what I think you are looking to do.